# Why does $\frac{1}{1-z}=-\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{z^n}$ if $|z|>1$

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series, taylor-expansion

Why does $$\frac{1}{1-z}=-\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{z^n}$$ if $|z|>1$ I know the case for $|z|<1$ and if $|z|>1 \implies |1/z|<1$ so $$\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{z}}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{z^n}$$ but I'm not seeing where the negative sign is coming from?

Comment: $\frac{1}{1-z} = \frac{1}{-z(1-\frac{1}{z})} $

Comment: It is not true. It is true that $$\frac{1}{1-z}=-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{z^n}$$ Note that the sum starts at $n=1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{1}{1-z}=\frac 1 z \cdot\frac{1}{\frac 1 z-1}=\color{red}-\frac 1 z\cdot\frac{1}{1-\frac 1 z}$$